# How to check if the error is #403 in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii2

I'm printing growl message if the user doesn't have access to use this function.

But now my code prints it anytime (despite the file is too big or the user doesn't have an access)

What I wanna do is to check if the error code is `#403` and if so, just then print that `growlMessage`. Could someone explain me how to do so?

Here's my jQuery function:

```
function fileInputError(event, data, msg) {
  setTimeout(function() {
     var nav = $('#nav-users');
     var progressBar = nav.find('.progress-bar');
     progressBar.removeClass('bg-success progress-bar-success')
        .addClass('bg-danger progress-bar-danger');
    progressBar.text('Error');  
  }, 110);

  growlMessage('You don't have permission to use this function.');
}
```

Comment: You question does not show enough information. 1. setTimout will be executed immediately and then your growl regardless with the code above. 2. I assume you are ajaxing, so put the growl in the error of the ajax or at least inside the function in the setTimeout

Comment: @mplungjan Since the name of the function is `fileInputError()`, I suspect it's called from the error handler of the ajax.

Comment: @Barmar The name sounded more like an error called when the extension was wrong - but as I said, not enough code to determine anything except that the growl is outside an async message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any ajax call in your code, if you want check the error code you can use statusCode

Use statusCode like :

```
$.ajax({
  statusCode: {
    403: function() {
      growlMessage('You don't have permission to use this function.');
    },
    500: function() {
      alert('500 status code! server error');
   }
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If this function is called from the `error:` option of `$.ajax`, e.g.

```
error: fileInputError,
```

the first argument is a [`jqXHR`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) object. You can get the status code from that.

```
function fileInputError(jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
  setTimeout(function() {
     var nav = $('#nav-users');
     var progressBar = nav.find('.progress-bar');
     progressBar.removeClass('bg-success progress-bar-success')
        .addClass('bg-danger progress-bar-danger');
    progressBar.text('Error');  
  }, 110);
  if (jqxhr.status == 403) {
    growlMessage('You don't have permission to use this function.');
  }
}
```